# How can I display only a particular line of the batch file output using C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, outputstream

I am creating a C# windows form application which would automatically detect the device connected to COM ports and display the COM port number in a label or text box. For easier implementation, I have created a batch file which gives me the information about the COM ports. So I run the batch file and store the output in a string called "result". For verification purposes, I display the output using "MessageBox.Show(result)". The next step is i would like to display only a particular line of the "result" in windows form using a label.

//label1.text = 9th line of the result//I'm looking for something like this

How can I do that? Is my approach right?

Here is the attached code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Programming();
    }

    private void Programming()
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\\Users\\vaka\\Desktop\\COM_Port_Detection.bat");
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
        {
            //
            // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
            //
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(result);
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have the extra `}` remove it or paste in the portion where you declare the namespace..

Comment: You could split your `result` using `result.Split('\n')` and take index 8 from it: `result.Split('\n')[8]`

Comment: Thank you @heinzbeinz. Was missing ".split". Will try it out.

Comment: Sorry about the extra "}". It does not appear to be in my code. I may have pasted it twice.  @MethodMan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read each line returned by the process separatly and then display only the 9th line:

```
using (StreamReader reader =  process.StandardOutput)
{
    var lines = new List<string>();
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        lines.Add(line);
    Console.Write(lines[8]);
    MessageBox.Show(lines[8]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm! :) @inwenis

Answer (score 0):

You have to "parse" the content you read from the other process to extract the required information/line.

One simple implementation could look like this:

```
string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
string[] lines = result.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (lines.Length >= 9)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lines[8]);
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: This method of implementation too worked well for my application! Thank you so much :) @Peter I am unable to accept both your suggestions as answers as website does not allow me but booth the answers worked well and served the purpose!